# How do I remove the arrows from shortcut icons in Windows?

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I am trying to eliminate the arrows from my shortcuts [image].

and watch the icons without that mark identifing as shortcut.

Im using Windows 8.1

Comment: Windows 8.4?  Let's hope that never happens.....

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Please indicate percisely which version of Windows you are using.  What "arrows" are you talking about.  Upload an image and provide us a url to a screenshot, you have to do something, your question due to the lack of clarify cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: I think he mean windows 8.1, as 4 is above 1 in numberpad

Comment: The arrow is an indicator that the object is a shortcut. That can be quite useful, and help you avoid undesired and odd situations where you are treating the shortcut as the useful data it's pointing to. For instance, you could "back up" the "file" and think to yourself "great! now let's format this disk". Only to find out later that your "file" is worthless garbage. But if you really want to do it, have a look at the proposed answer. That should cover it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to risk modifying your Registry, you can try the instructions listed [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-vista/how-to-remove-shortcut-arrows-from-vista-desktop-icons/).  It appears that tells Windows (all versions) to use a different way of creating the shortcut icons.

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the information from the link? This is best practice here on SuperUser, in case the link dies, we still have the information. Won't vote up until that information is here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you yo use this Tool:

[Ultimate Windows Tweaker 3](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-3-windows-8) For Windows 8 and 8.1

> While you may be able to access all these via the Windows 8.1 UI or
>   the Group Policy or Registry Editor, Ultimate Windows Tweaker makes
>   things easier for you by offering all useful tweaks from its single
>   UI. So consider it as a Tweak UI for Windows 8! Hover over any tweak
>   and helpful tool tips will tell you what the tweak does.

1. Download from the link listed above.
2. Execute the program with Admin Rights.
3. Go to Tab **File Explorer** and Press **Remove Shortcut Arrow From
   Shortcut Icons**. (See image)
4. Press Apply Button.
5. Restart your PC.

[image]

**WARNING: This 3rd Party Program works with the Windows Registry so be carefull what you press**